# Get GPS start/stop events with addGpsStatusListener

Tags: android, gps

In an application I would like to start a Service that can receive two
notification from GPS: GPS_EVENT_STARTED and GPS_EVENT_STOPPED.

To do so I've done the following code:

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestNotification extends Service {

    private LocationManager mLm;
    private MyListener mMyListener;

    private class MyListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {
        @Override
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            Log.i("MyGps", "Event");

            switch(event) {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                Log.i("MyGps", "Started");
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                Log.i("MyGps", "Stopped");
                break;
            }
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mLm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mMyListener = new MyListener();
        mLm.addGpsStatusListener( mMyListener );
    }
}
```

I also have set the following permission in manifest: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
I don't want to use requestLocationUpdates because it makes the GPS working 
everytime and send events when fixes change.

It test it on emulator and on real device (Eclair) but it doesn't work,
the Service never receive any notification.

I've read in detail the following thread ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/android-gps-status)) but no solution work. 
I send it in a separate question because I only want to be informed of 
GPS start and stop, not fixes.

Do you have any advice on this? 
May be it is because I try to do it in a Service rather that in an Activity?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I was using `GpsStatus.Listener` in Activity and I had the same problem. Somehow the listener didn't receive any GPS events. However, I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026549/how-can-i-monitor-the-status-of-the-gps-adapter-using-android-sdk) working pretty well. The idea is to use listener not on GPS status but on GPS settings.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this into AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.test.TestNotification" />
```