# How can I monitor the status of the GPS adapter using Android SDK?

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to have my app monitor whether the GPS adapter is anabled or disabled. I don't care about the actual GPS functionality running at the monemt or not -- I need the status of the GPS adapter.

I can manually do it by calling:

```
String providers = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
```

If "gps" is listed, then it's active, otherwise it's not. But I can't find any documentation on getting notified when GPS is enabled or disabled by the user. I did try to use addGpsStatusListener in LocationManager, but that only notifies when the actual GPS fix is being acquired (like if the Maps app is being used).

Any ideas?

Comment: What is a GPS _adapter_? Do you mean the GPS _receiver_ ? Or are you thinking of some NMEA interpreter library?

Comment: Can't you just use locationListener with a really high (Integer.MAX_VALUE) value for both time and location deltas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LocationContentObserver Nevermind, I found the answer;

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
    Settings.Secure.getUriFor(Settings.System.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED), 
            false, 
            new LocationContentObserver ( new Handler())
    );

class LocationContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
  public LocationContentObserver( Handler h ) {
    super( h );
  }

  public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
      SendNotification(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: why is  onChange getting called multiple times?