# Monitoring GPS receiver/adapter status

Tags: java, android, gps

I just need to monitor the status of GPS Receiver or adapter, cause my application don't want to work if gps is disabled manually by user...

Tried to use info from this link, but didn't help - [How can I monitor the status of the GPS adapter using Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026549/how-can-i-monitor-the-status-of-the-gps-adapter-using-android-sdk)

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the availability of GPS you can use the following code

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        //gps off. User turned the GPS off manually. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   boolean gpSstate = locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkState =locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if(!gpsState && !networkState) {// no GPS Service }
```