# Monitor GPS Usage on Android Device

Tags: android, gps, listener, monitoring

I am trying to set up a monitoring functionality on an Android device. I would like to monitor the actual usage of the GPS sensor on the phone. This means I am primarily not interested in when the user turns the GPS sensor on/off, but when he uses GPS data through any given app (e.g. maps, location based search).

I have tried the approach mentioned in [Get GPS start/stop events with addGpsStatusListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749539/get-gps-start-stop-events-with-addgpsstatuslistener), however, unsuccessfully.

It is also unclear to me whether GPS_EVENT_STARTED means a resume from standby of the sensor, or simply reflects toggling the "allow GPS" in the settings by the user. (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html)

Would someone know:

a) whether such a functionality is implementable/has already been implemented

b) how this could be accomplished?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After excessive testing of several approaches (a selection):
[How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)
[Android Enable and Disable GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015094/android-enable-and-disable-gps)
[How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake)
[How to enable GPS in android coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481695/how-to-enable-gps-in-android-coding)

I found that on Android v4.2.2 it was indeed not possible to toggle the GPS status (regardless of what exactly the status implies, as also asked in my question). I particularly found a comment in question [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker) to be *misleading*. Even if the exploit with the power control widget should have reemerged in 4.2.2, **it has since been fixed**.