# GPS is searching for too long

Tags: android, gps, gps-time

I have an app that uses the GPS.

My problem is that when I get to the part that the GPS is looking for a signal and cant find it, it just keeps on searching. This kills the battery.

I used this:

```
this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this.provider, 0,
                                            0, pendingIntent);
```

but it only sets the refresh rate.  If the GPS is not locked than it keeps on trying.

I want it to stop after a few minutes of trying to get a lock.

What can I do?

Comment: try changing the second argument from 0 to something higher.. 0 tells the locationmanager to constantly check the gps status

Comment: and where are you try ? in Emulator ? in Office ? both these places will not going to return GPS Value, you have to try it in device with open sky field.

Comment: Locifer- i want to fix the problam of when it cant get a gps. i want it to stop looking for a signal it it cant find it.
Gryphius - It was like you said before.  still, if it has a lock, it refreshes acording to that line of code, if it cant lock it will try to forever.

Comment: if you set it high enough, it should stop eventually, remember, the value is in milli seconds, try setting it to 300'000, iirc the gps will try to acquire a lock for about a minute, then stop, then retry 5 minutes later

Comment: can you please explain?  as i understand it, it only states the time intervals between locks not how much time it can "try" to lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to not check for new location frequently you have to specify minimum time and minimum distance. the structure is like this :

```
 public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, PendingIntent intent)
```

for more information check this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Edit : Sorry i don't understood your question. check this link, what you have to do is to set a timeout. Hope this help .
[How to time out GPS signal acquisition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725338/how-to-time-out-gps-signal-acquisition)

Comment: again, im not talking about the frequent of the checking for location, im talking about the time it spends to search for GPS each time.  i dont want him to do the searching for more than five minutes each time its searching.   thanks for your answer anyway.