# how to programmatically remove gps blinking icon from status bar in android (or make it never blink)?

Tags: android, gps, statusbar

In my android application which uses GPS, I have UI elemnts that should blink permanently. I was told after a couple of pilot runs that the blinking GPS icon, i.e. when GPS is actually trying to get a fix, steals completely unnecessary bit of user's attention from the main UI.

Is there a way to remove the GPS antenna icon from the status bar programmatically from within the application? Or, alternatively, make it never blink?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide the Status Bar altogether:

http://blog.thaichaiguy.com/1600/android-how-to-hide-the-status-bar-and-title-bar/

Comment: Nice find, however he said remove that specific icon from the status bar.. not hide it.. but I agree could be a good alternative although not many apps want to hide the title bar because it might be used for notifications and other info.

Comment: Yeah, since my app is just a custom one intended to check some different (research) finding, this option might indeed be a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is outside of the scope of the SDK and not possible.

Comment: Surely not in SDK, but appears to be easy to hack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4084800/296639