# My LocationListener is null in Android

Tags: android

In my app I am checking GPS strength. I get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:

```
listener==null.
```

I did not assign code listener to be null, and I write the code in the `OnCreate()` method. I don't know why listener turns null. Where am I going wrong?

My code:

```
public class Gps_strength extends Activity{
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationListener mGpsLocationListener;
    private GpsStatus.Listener gps_listener;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mGpsLocationListener);  // line no 31.
        mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gps_listener);
        if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == true) {
          ..... GPS strength checking coding..
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
    06-03 13:04:30.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2595): Caused by:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener==null
    06-03 13:04:30.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2595):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:627)
    06-03 13:04:30.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2595):     at com.gps.Gps_strength.onCreate(Gps_strength.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be ever setting `mGpsLocationListener` to equal anything.

---

Alter your declations to:

```
private LocationListener mGpsLocationListener = new LocationListener()
{

  public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
  {
  }

  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
  {
  }

  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
  {
  }

  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
  {
  }

};

private GpsStatus.Listener gps_listener = new GpsStatus.Listener()
{
  public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
  {
  }
};
```

Comment: how to set valid value for mGpsLocationListener instead of null

Comment: Murali have you gone through the url that i have replyed back to you

Answer (score 0):

You pass `gps_listener` as an argument to `mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener()`, but you never assign it to a valid object, so it is set to `null`.

Comment: i set as mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gps_listener); in code also. i post what i have code first. please assist me.

Comment: If you don't need to be notified when the GPS status changes, just comment out the `mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gps_listener);`.

Comment: i get the same error on the same line `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,mGpsLocationListener);` after comment out the `mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gps_listener);`

Comment: It's the same issue, `mGpsLocationListener` is `null`. You should have `mGpsLocationListener = new LocationListener { /* implementation here */ }`

Comment: yes i have coding as you told.expect declaration,every thing i wrote within oncreate method.

Comment: Edit your question and post the updated code, so we can see what's still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `private GpsStatus.Listener gps_listener;` The above statemnets is same as `private GpsStatus.Listener gps_listener = null;`
but in the code you have shown in nowhere the value of `gps_listener` is assigned. Directly you are assigning `gps_listener` to `mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gps_listener);`

First assign then use.

You can find sample code here
http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/

or

[How can I check the current status of the GPS receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/android-gps-status)

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: thanks how to set valid value for gps_listener instead of null. please guide me.

Comment: see my reponse now. Have a look on both the url.