# Gps status of android when launching the application

Tags: android, android-activity, gps

I want to find out the GPS status, when I launch the application. For that I previously used `LocationListener` class,
It was showing the status of the GPS when changing the GPS status in device only.

But here is my requirement: when I launch the app first it should check the GPS status, if GPS is available, only then I want to start the my activity and otherwise it needs to display some message to user like "Please enable GPS."

How can I do this?

Comment: refer this question might be useful to you : 
[How can I check the current status of the GPS receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks this method can help you:

```
public static boolean isGPSAvailable(Context ctx){

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    return lm != null &&
            (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
}//isGPSAvailable
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check your provider is null and ask the user to go to system settings to enable GPS

here is the code

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

    criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    if(provider==null){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Location Settings")
        .setMessage("Application needs your location,do you want to go to\n" +
                "system settings to enable your location source?")
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                try{

                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }})
         .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                LocationBasedServicesV1.this.finish();

            }

         })
        .show();
    }
```