# How to get Status of LocationProvider in android

Tags: android, gps, location, location-provider

I have written the below code for getting the best provider available.

```
private static String provider;

    public static String setCriteria(LocationManager locationManager) {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        LocationProvider locProvide = locationManager.getProvider(provider);        
        if (provider == null) {
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        }
        return provider;
    }
```

I am having this code to find the Provider which i will be using to get the Location. Now what i wish to check is that the status of the Provider. I read from doc that LocationProvider has 3states Available, Out of service & TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE. Now i before requesting to location listener i need to check the status.

**If the status is for e.g TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE or Out of Service then user will get the message accordingly else it will find the location. So my question how can i check the status?**

If anyone has any idea please kindly help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can Try using requestlocationupdates on your Locationmanager object and implement your Locationlistener object... like this..

```
   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, ll);

    private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
  ....

    @Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  switch(status){
   case 0:
   //OutofService
     break;
   case 1:
    //Temporarily unavailable
   break;
   case 2:
  //Available
    break;

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code that you have given. What i did is simply toast messages but nothing is happening. Can you tell me when onStatusChanged will be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , this is **[the ultimate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver)** for the above mentioned problem..and nothing can go beyond this
You just can tell isAvailable or not using the boolean variable `isGPSfix`

Though you can do other try [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151554/how-to-get-status-of-locationprovider-in-android) but that are not to guarranty to be work in all situation.