# How can I know if I lost my GPS fix?

Tags: android, gps

I know that I received a GPS fix if onLocationChanged() is called .. But how can I know if I lost the GPS fix ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver

Answer (score 0):

You stop receiving calls to onLocationChanged().

Comment: What if the user is standing still .. He has a GPS fix but his location doesn't change !

Comment: Have you tried this out?  Even if you're standing still, you will continue to get updates.