# Read the status of GPS on pressing home button in oncreate()

Tags: android, gps, status

In my application on button click I'm maKing the Gps "ON" or "OFF"

If GPS is ON then If we press home button, application will go to background then when the application comes to foreground once again the GPS should be in enabled(ON) position

something like this

```
  final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean statusOfGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(statusOfGPS == true){
              keep the GPS in "ON" position

    }
     else if(statusOfGPS == false){
        keep the GPS in "OFF" position
    }
```

How can we implement in oncreate() , so that when the application starts we can set the gps on or off by reading the state

Help is always appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you can not get GPS on Starting/Loading of the application, because GPS data takes time to fetch.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new thread, periodically check (for example once every 5 seconds) the status and correspondingly update GPS.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I dont want to check periodically

Answer (score 1):

> How can we implement in oncreate() , so that when the application
>   starts we can set the gps on or off by reading the state

So you can set the GPS on in `onResume()` method which is called when activity is going from background and in method for example `onPause()` set GPS off, this is called when activity is going to background.

When you want to check status of GPS, you can use `onGpsStatusChanged()` and call getGpsStatu( for get status of GPS or use `GpsStatusListener()`

```
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED) {
          // something to do

        } else if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED) {
            // something to do

        } else if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX) {
           // something to do
        }
```

Have look also at [How can I check the current status of the GPS receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver)

Comment: Thanks, for WIFI I could able to read the status in oncreate and its working for me, but not for gps. what could be the reason?

Comment: so i don't know immediately now exactly, there can be more reasons. but onCreate method isn't right place.