# android:I can not stop GPS update

Tags: android, gps, location

My app find out current location using `GPS`. It is working fine in outdoor. But where `GPS` is not available or poor it is trying to get update again and again and it drains battery. So i want to stop update when `GPS` is poor or unavailable. You may suggest to use

`lm.removeUpdates(locationlistenerforGPS);`

It is working fine when `GPS` is available not in indoor. I like to stop update when `GPS` is poor or unavailable.

my code is

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationlistenerforGPS = new mylocationlistenerGPS();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistenerforGPS);
```

My locationlistenerGPS() function is

```
 private class mylocationlistenerGPS implements LocationListener {
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      counterGPS++;
      if (location != null) {
      Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + " ");
      Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + " ");
      Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this,"latitude: "+
          location.getLatitude() + "longitude: " + location.getLongitude()
          + " Provider:" + location.getProvider() + " Accuracy:" + location.getAccuracy(),
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

  }
  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  }
  }
```

Thank you very much for any kind of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `minTime` and `minDistance` set to zero in `requestLocationUpdates()`. See [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) documentation.

Bundle extras in [onStatusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onStatusChanged%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) may include satellites - the number of satellites used to derive the fix, this way you can define poor signal or you can use [NmeaListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html) if you need additional information from GPS.

Comment: Mr.Biegleux thank you for reply. But `onStatusChanged()` is not working when `GPS` signal is poor or unavailable.My question is how can i stop the update when `GPS` is unavailable or poor?

Comment: Maybe try these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver and GpsStatus.Listener class.