# Why Android GPS is not shown location inside building?

Tags: android

I created an application using Android GPS. This application shows user's current location name, latitude and longitude, GPS accuracy in Android mobile. I have tested this application in my android device. It was run in my mobile perfectly. But I can not get location name, latitude, longitude and accuracy when I was in Home or building. How do I create Toast text when I am not getting GPS coverage?

Thanks.

Comment: There a literally dozens of reasons why it wouldn't work. Permissions? No GPS signal (you say you are "inside a bldg")? GPS/location services turned off?

Comment: For localisation within buildings when there is no GPS signal available I'd recommend libwlocate

Comment: Refer This Link for checking the GPS Status http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver

Comment: @debracey: I have getting location name, lat&long, accuracy out side of the building. But my problem is not getting location details inside the building.

Answer (score 6):

GPS works by connecting to four or more satellites and then triangulating your location by measuring the time it takes for the signal from various satellites to reach you, in a nutshell.

Due to this, you must have a clear view of the sky (sometimes even clouds can interfere), and GPS is unreliable and usually not working inside buildings and in underground locations.

Try using a different form of location tracking like the cell network for tracking the users inside buildings.

Comment: I accepted your answer. So is it possible to create Toast text when GPS signal is not available?

Comment: How to use cell network for tracking the userd inside buildings ? Any Example ?