# Using OnStatusChanged to switch to NETWORK_PROVIDER from GPS_PROVIDER?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

I'm working on an app that requires an accurate GPS fix. In the event that `GPS_PROVIDER` is enabled, but unavailable (like when you're in a tunnel), I want my app to switch to `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Can I use locationListener's `OnStatusChanged OUT_OF_SERVICE` to identify if a GPS fix cannot be made?

Something like this:

```
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    //0 = OUT_OF_SERVICE
    if (status == 0) {
        //try requesting updates using NETWORK_PROVIDER
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
        //TOAST MESSAGE: GPS UNAVAILABLE ATTEMPTING FIX WITH NETWORK
        ...
```

Am I'm using `OnStatusChanged` correctly? Is there a simple and better way of first attempting a GPS fix and if unavailable, switching to NETWORK?

Comment: `onStatusChanged()` [may not fire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver/3712727#3712727)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);` it will start fetching the location using network but once you come out from the Tunnel, it will start fetching from Network and GPS. Using `location.getProvider()` you should be able to differentiate to know whether it's gps or network.

If your GPS status isn't changing (e.g., if you're always indoors without a GPS fix) while the app is running, some devices won't trigger the `OnStatusChanged()` method.

If you change GPS statuses while the app is running (e.g., you're inside and can't get a fix and then walk outside and can get a fix, or vice versa), then the `OnStatusChanged()` method should fire on all devices.

If you want a fully working open-source app to use as an example, try GPSTest by Mike Lockwood from the Android team.

[GPSTest on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.gpstest)

[Source code for GPSTest](https://github.com/mikeandroid/gpstest)

For more detailed information about GPS that is constantly updated even if your device can't get a fix, you might want to register a GPSStatusListener.

In your Activity, declare class variables:

```
private LocationManager mService;
private GpsStatus mStatus;
```

...and add the method to handle the GPSStatus changes:

```
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
    mStatus = mService.getGpsStatus(mStatus);
    switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            // Do Something with mStatus info
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            // Do Something with mStatus info
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            // Do Something with mStatus info
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            // Do Something with mStatus info
            break;
    }
}
```

Then in OnCreate() of your Activity to register the GPSStatusListener:

```
mService = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mService.addGpsStatusListener(this);
```

In the GPSTest app, the list of currently available satellites is shown on the screen with each GPSStatusListener update, based on this [code](https://github.com/mikeandroid/gpstest/blob/master/src/com/android/gpstest/GpsStatusActivity.java).

This way, you'll receive active updates on the GPS status of system even if your phone can't get a GPS fix (and therefore may not trigger `OnStatusChanged` of the `LocationListener`).