# Android. How to know if location detected is from GPS or Network provider

Tags: android, gps, position, location-provider

I'm trying to implement an application which senses position from both GPS and the network provider and shows it on a Google Map. I succeeded in doing this, but I have a question:
I get the provider in the onCreate() of my Activity (it extends LocationListener)

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

It works fine, my problem is that when onLocationChange() is called, I should act differently if the provider which called it is GPS or NETWORK. Is there a way to know which?
To be more clear:

When `onLocationChanged(Location location)` is called, is there a chance to know which provider made the call? I have tried using an `if` on the provider string but it seems it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to know the Location provider (GPS, WIFI or Network) or its accuracy?

> [`getAccuracy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29)
>
> Get the estimated accuracy of this location, in meters.
>
> We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude, and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then there is a 68% probability that the true location is inside the circle.

If you really care about the provider, you could probably use [`isProviderEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks. I've seen isProviderEnabled(), my problem is that they are both enabled! I should know which provider have set the location in order to do different thing if it is GPS or NETWORK.

Comment: You should probably see the detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver

Answer (score 1):

check that accuracy is <= 30m:

```
boolean isGPS = (location.getAccuracy() <= 30);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've found out that there is a method ( location.getProvider() ) that seems to do what i want...I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna know which provider provided last Location update .....

u have created Provider as a string just use that String in code like 
if (provider.matches("GPS")){}

Answer (score 0):

I see several answers, and although they may be useful, none addresses the actual question asked:

> When onLocationChanged(Location location) is called, is there a chance to know which provider made the call?

To know whether it was `GPS_PROVIDER` or `NETWORK_PROVIDER` the one triggering the `onLocationChanged` you can use the `getProvider()` method (or the `provider` value in Kotlin):

```java
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    //obtain a string, 'gps' or 'network', from the location
    System.out.println(location.getProvider());
}
```

Or in Kotlin:

```kotlin
override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
    println(location!!.provider)     
}
```

Doc reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider())