# iOS CoreLocation: Is it possible to know if the location data is coming from GPS or from Wifi?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I was wondering if we can get the source type of the current location in iOS. I didn't find any reference nor in `CLLocationManager` neither in `CLLocation`.

I've found the same question here in SO, but for Android:

- [Is it possible to know my location came from gps or glonass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655011/is-it-possible-to-know-my-location-came-from-gps-or-glonass)
- [Android. How to know if location detected is from GPS or Network provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321926/android-how-to-know-if-location-detected-is-from-gps-or-network-provider)

The second one has an answer that says if the accuracy is smaller than 30 meters, than it is using GPS. But I don't know if we really can assume that.

Comment: I don't believe you have any way of knowing for sure.  Accuracy is your best clue

Comment: But is 30 meters a fair number? Do you know where does it come from?

Comment: I don't think you can ever know that you aren't using GPS, but you can make a pretty good guess that you *are*.  If your accuracy is 10m then you are using GPS.  If it is 30 you may be using WiFi or GPS.  I assume the figure of 30 comes from the typical distance  over which a WiFi signal can be "seen"

Comment: Great explanation, Paul. Thank you very much. I think you can add an answer for this question and then I accept it.