# Use only GPS for iOS device location

Tags: ios, core-location

I need to know if the GPS device component of my users is healthy, so i want to get the location ONLY by the GPS and **NOT** form wifi or surrounding antennas.

I'm forcing my users to close their wifi before this operation so i definitely know that the received signal is not from the wifi (because its possible).

I tried to work with the `CLLocationManager` and `CLLocation`'s horizontalAccuracy.
some people say that when the horizontalAccuracy is lower than 160 it means we have a good GPS strength, but its not perfect at all..

I also tried to create an array of [`CLLocation`] after calling [locationManager startUpdatingLocation], and than i saw that when i'm in a place like a basement(with no GPS signal), my array's count was lower that a situation with signal because the updates frequency is lower.. **but** this is not a perfect solution either..

I just want to be sure that the GPS component is definitely working and the location that i get is from the GPS.
so, any solution please?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29188387/1849664

Comment: hey, thanks but there is no answer there and its from 3 years ago..

Comment: You can’t force the use of GPS. You can ask for “best” accuracy which will enable the GPS and if you get a horizontal accuracy of about 10m then you know GPS was used.  With a higher horizontal accuracy figure, GPS may have been used, but what does it matter; the location is still inaccurate.

Comment: Curious what kind of app are you making? I mean navigation apps require the most accuracy and recommend to use wi-fi. Obviously it's better in highly congested areas...

Comment: My app is checking all the device components health. so i have to be SURE that the GPS is OK. my app called TestM and its available in the Appstore and Playstore.