# How to know whether gps is locked(got fix) or still searching in android

Tags: android, gps, location

In my android app, i'm playing with user location. Problem is I want to know whether GPS is locked or still it is trying to get i.e, is there flag or some method to know, the moment GPS is locked?

Comment: I made some code that handles this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365035/location-servise-gps-force-closed/19366773#19366773

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html

This might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location.getProvider().equals("gps")) {
        //FROM GPS
        if(isSearching){//GPS called first time after Enable
            isSearching=false;
        }
    } else {
        //FROM NETWORK

    }
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    isSearching = true;
    // GPS IS SEARCHING
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
```

}

Raise a flag whenever the user enables the gps. OnLocationChanged is never called until the gps is fixed.

Comment: I believe this will give a false positive, as onLocationChanged will get called despite GPS not being ready. At least if using network for location too.

Comment: This might help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453576/android-check-if-gps-is-searching-has-fix-or-is-not-in-use/20812298?noredirect=1#comment31380852_20812298