# Service does not give the correct Location

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, locationlistener

I have a service running in which I implement "Location Listener", basically i create my LocationManager like this:

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000*2,0, this);
```

and i try to make a string on my `onLocationChanged(Location location)` like this:

```
route = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
```

The problem is that unless i wait a lot of time my Listener won't get the location updates, because gps_provider takes its time to get ready.

I have all the permissions in the manifest for this feature, and i ask for gps to be enabled before starting this service.

Is there any option for making my app wait until the gps is ready?

I want my app to wait until the GPS is ready to give locations, just to tell the user that he/she must wait until that moment to start.

Comment: Please clarify your question, you want your app to wait until GPS is ready?  how will the app wait? what should not occur? and do you really want a margin of 30 seconds between location tracks?

Comment: Yes, i want my app to wait until GPS is ready. I dont mind how it waits (ProgressDialog or similar), i just want to tell the user of the app that he/she must wait some time. And finally the 30 seconds were for the example, i dont want 30 seconds in the final version.

Comment: Did  you see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453576/android-check-if-gps-is-searching-has-fix-or-is-not-in-use

Comment: And how is it hard to display a loading dialog which blocks the user interactions and dismiss it when onLocationChanged(Location location) is invoked?

Comment: GPS Does't work well some time  on basement any or  ground area also. may be problem, i just suppose