# Can I get a GPS fix status on Android through NMEA

Tags: android, gps

I'd like to display a GPS status icon in my application to indicate whether or not there's a valid fix to the user. There seem to be a few ways to do this, including using the API directly (which seems to have poor results based on some of the questions on SO) and guessing that a GPS fix has been dropped after a certain time has elapsed ([How can I check the current status of the GPS receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver))

Android apparently lets you grab NMEA strings directly as well:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html

One of the NMEA Tokens ($GPGGA) gives you fix quality information:

```
 GGA          Global Positioning System Fix Data
 123519       Fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC
 4807.038,N   Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N
 01131.000,E  Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E
 1            Fix quality: 0 = invalid
                           1 = GPS fix (SPS)
                           2 = DGPS fix
                           3 = PPS fix
                           4 = Real Time Kinematic
                           5 = Float RTK
                           6 = estimated (dead reckoning)
                           7 = Manual input mode
                           8 = Simulation mode
 08           Number of satellites being tracked
 0.9          Horizontal dilution of position
 545.4,M      Altitude, Meters, above mean sea level
 46.9,M       Height of geoid (mean sea level) above WGS84
                  ellipsoid
 (empty field) time in seconds since last DGPS update
 (empty field) DGPS station ID number
 *47          the checksum data, always begins with *
```

It seems like I can just check that my fix status isn't 0,6,7, or 8 to see if I have a fix. But I have a few questions:

1. Is it reasonable to expect all Android GPS receivers provide NMEA strings?
2. If yes to 1, will all Android GPS receivers provide NMEA strings at regular intervals?

The separate/USB GPS receivers that I've played around with just broadcast NMEA strings at regular intervals (ie, even without a fix) so its easy to check whether or not there's a fix. I don't know if this behavior is defined by any kind of standard and is something I can rely on.

I know that not all GPS receivers broadcast NMEA strings and some transmit a closed protocol... but I don't know whether or not these kinds of receivers are used in typical retail Android devices.

Comment: have you find answer on your question? I have a similar issue. maybe you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917764/gpgga-and-gprmc-sentences-are-not-received-in-onnmeamessage