# How can I check if GPS is enabled before I try to use it

Tags: java, android, gps

I have the following code and it's not good because sometimes GPS takes very long

How can I do the following:

1. Check if GPS is enabled
2. Use GPS if it is enabled otherwise use the network provider.
3. If GPS takes more than 30 seconds, use network.

I can do this with my own logic using a time or Thread.sleep but I think there might be a more stabndard way

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        locationCallback(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: Think again of your 3rd condition. raise it to 60s. 30s often works only with AGPS using internet.

Answer (score 11):

There's no standard way to do this, you have to do it on your own with the help of:

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    //Do what you need if enabled...
} else {
    //Do what you need if not enabled...
}
```

And this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

As recommendation if GPS is not enabled, usually the standard specifies to popup the Location Settings Activity so the user can specifically enable it...

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: Also, to make the call as shown in this answer, you need to add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

Answer (score 10):

Just using this code, you can check `GPS` availability:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);;
boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you could use the code in my answer to: [Location servise GPS Force closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365035/location-servise-gps-force-closed/19366773#19366773)

It gives you a callback method for GPS first fix and location changes that can be very convenient. This also makes it easy to change the implementation of GPSTracker to switch to network if GPS takes too long to get a first fix.