# Is there a robust implementation or library for getting an accurate location efficiently and quick as possible?

Tags: java, android, location

I need to get the most accurate location within 40 seconds.

I know I need to check which providers are enabled, try each of them for the last know location and if it's old or the accuracy is bad then I need to get a network location and check its accuracy if it's bad then I need to fire up GPS and wait max 40 seconds before using the network location.

I am sure this has been done many many times before and I'm wondering if there is a good implementation that I can copy rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't know about library but accuracy depends on GPS or your network service provider. I don't think you can code for accuracy at your end.
Note: GPS gives most accurate location than network provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my answer to this question: [Location servise GPS Force closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365035/location-servise-gps-force-closed/19366773#19366773)

I have implemented the GPSTracker to give callbacks for location changes and for GPS first fix.

Just when GPSTracker has been created it returns the lastKnownLocation until a first fix has been made.