# Android App - GPS data to Web Server

Tags: android, http, gps, request

Can anybody tell my if there is any application that sends GPS data in JSON format on URL by HTTP request (GET OR POST) ?

Thank you.

Martin Kejzlar

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please rephrase your question so that others can understand it and reply accordingly.

Comment: I wouldn't know, but that wouldn't be hard to make.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you could easily build this yourself.

I have made my own version of the GPSTracker from: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

You can find it here: [Location servise GPS Force closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365035/location-servise-gps-force-closed/19366773#19366773)

It supports callbacks for when GPS has gained a First-Fix and location changes. When implemented for your purpose, simply send the data to your server in the onLocationChanged callback.