# Error getting Location Android (GPS and Network)

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I want to get the location in my APP using the following code:

```
public Location getLocation() {     

    boolean isGPSEnabled     = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    try {   

        // Getting GPS and Network status
        isGPSEnabled     = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) return null;

        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location                = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if ((location != null && (location.getTime() + 60000 < System.currentTimeMillis())) || 
                location == null){
            location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }                           

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return null;
    }

    return location;
}
```

When I am using a Nexus 4 it works properly and location has a value. But when I am executing the same code in a Galaxy S2 location = null.

Before calling the function I have checked that GPS and Network are both enabled.

How would you correcte this function?

Before calling this function I call this one:

```
public void startLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);    

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device have not yet found a location, it will return null.

I bet if your open Google Maps and let it locate you before opening your app, it will work as expected.

See my answer to [Location servise GPS Force closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365035/location-servise-gps-force-closed/19366773#19366773). 
This is an example on how you can implement a callback to let you know as soon as a location is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to trigger it by calling one of the .request... functions.