# Show current location from google maps without clicking button

Tags: android, google-maps, button

i need help as soon as possible, right now, i have developed a app that must show current Location Client, and i have try http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html and its work well,  but i want to show the client location  without clicking the button, i have try to change the memthod getLocation(), but everytime i have tried to call method getLocation(), my app always error,

nb:  i have removed the parameter of getLocation() and the xml i already change too. i have try to put the method in onCreated and also in onStart, it's error

anybody can help me please﻿ to solve my problem?

Comment: I think you are facing the same issue as I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825256/error-getting-location-android-gps-and-network/19825506#19825506

Comment: i have try yours, but it's still not work, in the tutorial there getLocation(View v), in my project i have try to change it without parameter, but when i call the method in onCreated it give error, so how ican solve it, or can i add the code here so its clear

Comment: Yes please add your code. Seems odd for getLocation to take a View. By the way, my code does not handle zooming in to current location, you would have to do that in onLocationChanged using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074129/google-maps-v2-set-both-my-location-and-zoom-in

Answer (score 0):

for Google map v2(the latest version),you should implements the [LocationSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.html)  to update current location , than also you do need make a location request use [LocationClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) to get current location then update it with [LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener.html)