# android : implementing GpsStatus.Listener

Tags: android, gps

I have read all questions on this matter, they don't cover what I need — maybe because what I want is too basic, or the error I'm facing is too weird.

Anyhow, I want to implement `GpsStatus.Listener`.  What I have done is:

```
private class myGpsStatus implements GpsStatus.Listener{

@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {

    int SatellitesInFix = 0;
    int timetofix = locationMangaer.getGpsStatus(null).getTimeToFirstFix();

    for (GpsSatellite sat : locationMangaer.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites()) {
        if(sat.usedInFix()) {
            SatellitesInFix++;              
        }
        Satellites++;
        CALLSTH();

    }
```

But, when I declared :

```
GpsStatus.listener = new myGpsStatus();
```

I faced this error which says:

> listener cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: That `>>>listener<<<` part is a typo, isn't it? Otherwise won't compile.

Comment: If it is a GPS first-fix you need, I have posted an implementation in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365035/location-servise-gps-force-closed/19366773#19366773 please upvote if it helps you.

Comment: @MisterSmith no, Im using those to gain attention to what part error is referring.

Comment: @cYrixmorten thanks. Ill get to it asap