# How to handle Location Listener updates inside a Service in Android?

Tags: android, service, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on an app that should get accurate user location continuously if user is inside a specific zone.
The location updates should be saved on a server (Parse.com) so other users can get the current location of the user.

The flow is:

1. Application onCreate -->
2. start Service with LocationListener -->
3. onLocationChanged -->
4. save new location on Parse.com -->
5. Parse.com Cloud afterSave method send push notification to users -->
6. other users get notifications via broadcast reciever -->
7. update user marker on map <--

Questions:

1. I am not sure about how to implement step 4, should I save the new location on parse inside the onLocationChanged method? should I pass it to a BroadcastReciever and save it on parse there? or should I pass it to a static method in my CurrentUser class that will perform the save on server?
2. I have noticed the requestLocationUpdates documentation says:

   > "This method is suited for the foreground use cases, more specifically
   >   for requesting locations while being connected to LocationClient. For
   >   background use cases, the PendingIntent version of the method is
   >   recommended."

   In my case, which method should I use?
3. What values should I use for getting almost real time location without consuming more than 5% of battery power per hour?

My Service Class:

```
public class UserTracker extends Service implements
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

static int GEOFENCE_STATUS; 
final static int INSIDE_GEOFENCE = 9001, OUTSIDE_GEOFENCE = 9002;

static final int MINIMUM_ACCURACY = 26;

final static int GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 2000;

static final int NULL_LOCATION_ERROR = 7001;

static final int INSIDE_INTERVAL = 10000, INSIDE_FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000, INSIDE_SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 10;
static final int OUTSIDE_INTERVAL = 300000, OUTSIDE_FASTEST_INTERVAL = 60000, OUTSIDE_SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 100;

static Location eventLocation;

LocationClient lc;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    eventLocation = new Location("Test");
    lc = new LocationClient(getApplicationContext(), this, this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    double eventLat = intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude", -1);
    double eventLon = intent.getDoubleExtra("Longitude", -1);
    if (eventLat == -1 || eventLon == -1) {
        stopSelf();
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    eventLocation.setLatitude(eventLat);
    eventLocation.setLongitude(eventLon);

    lc.connect();

    return START_STICKY;
}

public int getGeofenceStatus(Location currentLocation) {
    if (currentLocation == null) {          
        return NULL_LOCATION_ERROR;         
    } 
    if (currentLocation.distanceTo(eventLocation) > GEOFENCE_RADIUS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "User is outside geofence");
        return OUTSIDE_GEOFENCE;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "User is inside geofence");
        return INSIDE_GEOFENCE;
    }
}

public void requestLocationUpdates(int status) {

    GEOFENCE_STATUS = status;

    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();

    switch (status) {
    case NULL_LOCATION_ERROR:
        stopSelf();
        break;
    case INSIDE_GEOFENCE:           
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        request.setInterval(INSIDE_INTERVAL);
        request.setFastestInterval(INSIDE_FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        request.setSmallestDisplacement(INSIDE_SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);
        break;
    case OUTSIDE_GEOFENCE:
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        request.setInterval(OUTSIDE_INTERVAL);
        request.setFastestInterval(OUTSIDE_FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        request.setSmallestDisplacement(OUTSIDE_SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);         
        break;
    }
    lc.requestLocationUpdates(request, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int newStatus = getGeofenceStatus(location);
    int accuracy = (int) location.getAccuracy(); 

    String message = "Geofence status: " + newStatus + 
            "\nAccuracy: " + accuracy + 
            "\nDistance to event: " + location.distanceTo(eventLocation);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (newStatus == INSIDE_GEOFENCE && accuracy < MINIMUM_ACCURACY) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Accuracy is good");
                    // do the save on server procees
    }
    if (GEOFENCE_STATUS != newStatus) {
        requestLocationUpdates(newStatus);
    }       
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "LocationClient connection failed: " + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Location currentLocation = lc.getLastLocation();
    requestLocationUpdates(getGeofenceStatus(currentLocation));
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "LocationClient disconnected");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}       
}
```

Comment: Is the location update is continuous in service?
Does it stops ??