# Android: get current, high accuracy location only on request - which strategy?

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to get current position with the highest accuracy on user requests. 
He presses a button - app saves start location, he does it again - it saves stop location.

I decided to use Location Client from Google Play Services. But I'm still wondering whether I need to keep method onLocationChanged(Location location) updated all the time, according to setInterval time?

Maybe I should change interval? Or after getting start location removeLocationUpdates() and then requestLocationUpdates() again ?

I also tried with getLastLocation() but without requestLocationUpdates() each time I got the same coordinates.

Perhaps in this case LocationManager will be better? It has methods like requestSingleUpdate() or requestLocationUpdates() + removeUpdates() ?

Comment: You should not forget that to receive highly accurate location you need to use GPS_PROVIDER, which always requires at least 15-20 seconds to launch and establish connection with satellites. If accuracy is important and you cannot wait for GPS connection, you should receive location updates all the time and store last accurate location in some object to have possibility to achieve it immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Right, in my case GPS_PROVIDER is a must. Just wondering whether I really need onLocationChanged(Location location) periodically updated by LocationListener if I need position only on request? Would be nice to have getLastLocation() working...

Comment: Have a look at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365035/location-servise-gps-force-closed/19366773#19366773 you can use the GPS first fix callback as demonstrated.

Comment: @tomek by getLastLocation() you just receive some location that is stored in cache on previous request, by your or other running apps. Very often it is outdated, you can check the time it was obtained by location.getTime()

Comment: @cYrixmorten thanks, seems very promising.

Comment: No problem, have used it with great success myself

Comment: @Salauyou But if I want to get position on user request, not on location changed event then what I should call ? I guess that: 1. use requestLocationUpdates(...) 2. keep onLocationChanged(..) empty 3. call getLastLocation(...) on user request. Right?

Comment: @tomek.ceszke just create one Location object and overwrite it on every onLocationChanged() event, use its data when user requests.

Comment: @tomek.ceszke when GPS is active, it sends location updates frequently enough not to be worry that it is outdated. You can manage frequency and accuracy by requestLocationUpdates() arguments. And you can always check the time it was received as I mentioned before--to make sure that last location is exactly what you need.

Comment: I see. Just thought that getLastLocation does the same. Thanks again!