# Crash onLocationChanged() Android

Tags: java, android, android-location

I am getting a crash in `onLocationChanged()` method and this is what I get in logCat

```
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132): Process: com.dd.assistant, PID: 4132
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at com.twixkat.assistant.MainActivity.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:1314)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-10 00:51:43.354: E/AndroidRuntime(4132):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    if (arg0 != null) {
        double longitude = arg0.getLongitude();
        double latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        citylb.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        getWeather((String) citylb.getText());

        // if (addresses.size() > 0) return addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    }

}
```

I followed some tutorials and I don't know why application crashes!! Thank You!!

Comment: What is on MainActivity.java line 1314?

Comment: this: `citylb.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());`

Comment: At that point are you 100% sure you have added at least 1 element to your list?

Comment: @m0skit0 what? What do you mean?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A

Comment: How could help me this video????

Comment: i think i posted enought not? you can't help me?

Comment: Generally into the stacktrace the "Caused by: " tell us about the specific exception and line.

Comment: Ok, consider that not always crash.. so i have to wait.. Now i write to get the log with exceptio. Just wait few minute i think

Comment: as soon as i have the stacktrace i post it here

Comment: only this: `Error java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server` and what i have written before in the quest

Comment: seems like citylb is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);` sometimes returns null. See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29).

Try to handle this situation. For example:

```
try {
    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.e("MyTag", "MyMessage", e); // use this instead e.printStackTrace();
}

if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0){
    citylb.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());

    getWeather((String) citylb.getText());
}else{
    citylb.setText("No adresses found");
}
```

Comment: Roman i need your help again.. can i contact you on hangout? Thanks

Comment: Mmh but i need your account :) can you send me an email? dellai.davide@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You will have two causes for this exception:

1) your `citylb` might not have been initialized.

```
private TextView citylb;

citylb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewIdinLayout);
```

2)
at this line of code :

```
citylb.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

`addresses` has a null value or is empty!

Comment: i already declared both things but `citylb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewIdinLayout);` in my onCreate() method.. is it correct?

Comment: It's Not the problem..it crashes anyway. Have I to post more code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `addresses` is null. Simply move the rest to the try block and catch all `Exception`:

`try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
citylb.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        getWeather((String) citylb.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // GeoCoder service not available
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Comment: And if inside the try block I insert an if condition? `if (addresses.get(0).getLocality() == null) {        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       } else {        citylb.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());        getWeather((String) citylb.getText());       }` should works Not?

Answer (score 0):

**addresses** is null, geocoder returns null for unknown locations, you have to test it's result before using it!