# Android: how to know when GPS signal is lost

Tags: android, gps, android-location, nmea

I have to notify the user when the GPS signal is lost (like the Maps app does), but I've searched through the internet and it doesn't seem to exist a way to do it... or I didn't understand it.

Somebody knows how to do it?

I'v tried with `GpsStatus.Listener` and `GpsStatus.NmeaListener` but there are no callbacks that point out the loss of GPS connection...

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2022869/1230782

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get no. of sattelite

```
Location location
int a = location.getExtras().getInt("satellites") ;
if (a > 4) {

}
else {
    singal loss
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this can be a solution? How can I have a Location if i have lost signal?

Comment: by using  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 
  
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,   // 3 sec
    5, this);
    boolean isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(!isGPS)
   {
    showSettingsAlert();
    
    
   }

Comment: and implements its method in that write this