# How to update the user location after enabling the GPS from an in App prompt

Tags: android

I am currently developing an Android app which prompts the user to enable GPS if it's not on and I have used AlertDialog for this purpose. After I enable the GPS from settings and come back to my app by pressing back button, the mapView doesn't reflect my current location. Although If I have my GPS on before running the app, the app properly displays my location. I want to know to which method to use for this refresh user location after enabling GPS purpose. Any relevant article would really help.

Following is my code for the GPS part:

**GPSTracker.java**

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// Flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// Flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// Flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // Location
double latitude; // Latitude
double longitude; // Longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

/******/




/****/


public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        // Getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // No network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {

                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
 */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}


/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}


/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog.
 * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
 */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing the Settings button.
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // On pressing the cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

The following class makes use of above class to display location in a mapView

**LocationActivity.java**

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

Button btnGPSShowLocation;
Button btnSendAddress;
Button find_rick;
TextView tvAddress;

AppLocationService appLocationService;

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

//Google maps implementation
GoogleMap googleMap;

private static final String TAG = LocationActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_layout);

    createMapView();


    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGPSShowLocation);
    btnSendAddress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendAddress);




            gps = new GPSTracker(LocationActivity.this);

            // Check if GPS enabled and if enabled  after popup then call same fn
            MapMyCurrentLoction();


    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        MapMyCurrentLoction();
        }
    });


    btnSendAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                String tag_string_req_send_data = "req_send";

                StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        AppConfig.URL_AUTOWALA_DHUNDO, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Autowala Response: " + response.toString());


                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                            if (!error) {
                                // User successfully stored in MySQL
                                // Now store the user in sqlite
                                Log.d("Autowale ka data","success");
                            } else {

                                // Error occurred in data sending. Get the error
                                // message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Data sending Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            // Posting params to register url
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("tag", "data_send");
                            params.put("latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
                            params.put("longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));


                            return params;
                        }

                    };

                    // Adding request to request queue
                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req_send_data);

            }
        });

}

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        MapMyCurrentLoction();
        //super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        addMarker(latitude,longitude);
        //super.onResume();
}

private void createMapView(){
    /**
     * Catch the null pointer exception that
     * may be thrown when initialising the map
     */
    try {
        if(null == googleMap){
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            /**
             * If the map is still null after attempted initialisation,
             * show an error to the user
             */
            if(null == googleMap) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error creating map",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException exception){
        Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a marker to the map
 */
private void addMarker(double lat,double lng){

    /** Make sure that the map has been initialised **/
    if(null != googleMap){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(lat,lng))
                        .title("Your Location")
                        .draggable(true)
        );

        //zooming to my location
        float zoomLevel = 16.0F; //This goes up to 21
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, zoomLevel);
        googleMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
    }
}

private void MapMyCurrentLoction(){
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        addMarker(latitude,longitude);

                /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
        String area = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addressList = null;
        try {
            addressList = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getCountryName());
            area = sb.toString();
        }

        // \n is for new line
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude + "\n"+area, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  else {
        // Can't get location.
        // GPS or network is not enabled.
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
        gps.showSettingsAlert();

        //Again search and map my location after enabling gps

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any relevant code to show? :)

Comment: A little searching revealed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver

Comment: I have added my java files.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize this

```
     gps = new GPSTracker(LocationActivity.this);
```

at onResume() and at onCreate() and if needed then at onRestart() too.
This is not the correct way but for making it working you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

you`re probably interest in 'onResume' method. After getting back to Activity this one is invoked. Sho in there you should update the position