# Check if user disable GPS in settings in android

Tags: android

There is any solution to check if user disable GPS in settings? 
I open my app, open top toolbar of android system, disable GPS and close this toolbar. In this moment I want to app check if status of GPS was changed.
I use check if GPS is active in onResume(), but this solution works only when user enable GPS, when disable onResume() is not called.
Any ideas?

Edit:
This is may class:

```
public class PrivacyActivity extends BaseActivity  implements GpsStatus.Listener, LocationListener{


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_privacy);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
   }

   @Override
   public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
      switch (event) {
         case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            Toast.makeText(this, "ads", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
         case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            Toast.makeText(this, "ads1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ads2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ads2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ads2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

and when I disable gps I didn't see toast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the current status of the GPS receiver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021176/how-can-i-check-the-current-status-of-the-gps-receiver)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LocationListener class

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.i("Example", "GPS is ON");
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.i("Example", "GPS is OFF");
    }
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You can get more info in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

Reference the locationListener first.

```
LocationListener locationListener;

locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            LatLng myPlace = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPlace).title("me"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPlace));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8.0f));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

onProviderDisabled method will be fired if the user has disabled GPS from settings.
The intent inside the method will take the user to location settings directly.

Tested and works fine.